# When executing async database inserts how do you ensure the query data being inserted lives long enough?

Tags: rust

I am using these crates: tokio-postgres, rust_decimal, chrono and bb8 (connection pooling library).

I give the quick summary up top here and then a detailed explanation underneath. Basically with my query data:

```
let data_array = [
    &data.id,
    &data.currency_id,
    &data.price,
    &data.date_time,
];
```

I put it into a future query:

```
let the_query = client.execute(&statement, &data_array)
query_futures.push(the_query);
```

Then later on I do a `futures::future::join_all(query_futures).await;` which executes all the inserts together. But this means the data may not live long enough, causing the well known borrowed value does not live long enough error.

How can I fix this? I have tried *many* things!

Here is the full code:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
id: i32,
currency_id: i64,
price: Decimal,
date_time: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}

let mut query_futures = Vec::with_capacity(trades.len());

while (some_condition) {

    //these three lines work fine:
    let pool = pg_connection.clone().connection_pool.unwrap().clone();
    let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();
    let statement = client
    .prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, currency_id, price, date_time) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4").await.unwrap();

    //this for loop batches together the query futures into a single future
    for (another_condition) {

        let currency_id = 34 as i64;
        let price = Decimal::new(0, 3);
        let mut data  = MyStruct {
            id: 23 as i32,
            currency_id: currency_id,
            price: price,
            date_time: NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(
                SystemTime::now()
                .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
                .unwrap()
                .as_secs() as i64,
                0,
            )
        }

     //HERE IS WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM:

        let data_array = [
            &data.id as &(dyn ToSql + Sync),
            &data.currency_id,
            &data.price,
            &data.date_time,
        ];

        let the_query = client.execute(&statement, &data_array);
        query_futures.push(the_query);

    }
    let queries = futures::future::join_all(query_futures);
    queries.await;
}
```

Note I use the `as &(dyn ToSql + Sync) trait` to ensure each item of the slice is of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is with an `async move` closure. That will take ownership of the parameters you're trying to pass lend into the array, which can then be lent to `execute`:

```rust
let data = MyStruct { ... };   
// Need to explicitly borrow `statement` so that the
// future doesn't try to take ownership of it
let statement = &statement;

query_futures.push(async move {
     let data_array = [
        &data.id as &(dyn ToSql + Sync),
        &data.currency_id,
        &data.price,
        &data.date_time,
    ];

    client.execute(statement, &data_array).await
})
```

It's tangential to your question, but unless you need these insertions to specifically be ordered, I'm going to recommend you use `FuturesUnordered` instead of `join_all` to handle the concurrency for these tasks.